# Recyclerview Adapter's notifyDataSetChanged not updating RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, sql, arrays, database

I have a `RecyclerView` for chat app with firebase realtime database and local SQLite database. I am saving message into local database (SQLite) then calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

If the message is already in the database (message unique id) then SQLite will return 0 on database `insertOrThrow` method. I am checking the availability like this.

```
if (id == 0) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Database Already Has Value Of This Random Id ");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
} else {
    Chat_Wrapper chat_wrapper = new Chat_Wrapper(Chat_Msg, null, null, null, null, null, null, Chat_TimeStamp, UserPhone_Intent, UserImage_Intent, Chat_FROM, null,null,id);
    message.add(chat_wrapper);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

However, even the `else` statement is being called, my `RecyclerView` screen is not updated, but in the background, if I type or receive any message it saves into the local database but doesn't show on screen.

Chat `RecyclerView` works in following cases

1. When I clear app from recent app
2. Stop Fetching data from the local database
3. First Launch of Chat screen

I am facing this issue when I come directly to chat screen from notification.

That's How I load chat fragment normally.

`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.Navigation_Drawer, chatFragment).commit();`

Loading `Fragment` from `Notification` using `Asynctask`

```
((Navigation_Drawer)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Navigation_Drawer, chatFragment).commit();
```

That's how i launches ChatFragment from notification.

```
public class FireBase_Messaging_Service extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static final String TAG="###FireBase MSG###";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION=5;
    String UserName;
    String ID;
    String Msg;

    Map<String,String> data;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d(TAG,"From "+remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
            data = remoteMessage.getData();
            Log.d(TAG,"Message Data "+remoteMessage.getData());
            data = remoteMessage.getData();

            UserName = data.get("name");
            ID = data.get("ID");
            Msg = data.get("Message");

            showNotification(Msg,ID,UserName);
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Message Notification Body "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
           // Toast.makeText(this, "Notification "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void showNotification(String Message,String ID,String UserName) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Show Notification "+Message+" "+ID);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, Navigation_Drawer.class);
        intent.putExtra("Type","Text");
        //intent.putExtra("Type",MsgType);
        intent.putExtra("ID",ID);
        intent.putExtra("uname",UserName);
        intent.putExtra("Message",Msg);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,NOTIFICATION,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.black);
        String ChannelID = "Message";
        notificationChannel(ChannelID,"Chat");
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),ChannelID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default_x)
                .setColor(color)
                .setContentTitle(UserName)
                .setContentText(Message)
                .setChannelId(ChannelID)
                .setTicker("My App")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS)
                .setLights(0xff00ff00, 1000, 500) // To change Light Colors
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(Message))//For Expandable View
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION,builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
    }

    private void notificationChannel (String ChannelID, String channelName) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel  channel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelID,channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

I also noticed by logging that after adding data to list `message.add(chat_wrapper)` it first showing an increase in size but when while loop is over, it shows the last size of the `ArrayList`.

Here's the `ChatFragment` class.

```
 public class Chat_Screen_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, ChildEventListener{

    public static final String TAG = "###CHAT SCREEN###";
    List<Chat_Wrapper> message = new ArrayList<>();

    Chat_Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_screen_main_fragment,container,false);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        // GET INTENT VALUES FROM USER PROFILE CLASS

        UserName_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_Name");
        UserImage_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_Image");
        UserPhone_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_Phone");
        UserID_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_ID");
        FirebaseToken_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_Token"); //Firebase Token of other person
        Room_Name_Intent = getArguments().getString("Get_Other"); // Room Name of chat
        UserLastSeen_Intent=getArguments().getString("LastSeen");
        //Sender_FCMToken = Session.getFirebaseID();
        // RECYCLER VIEW
        recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.Chat_Screen_Message_List);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Room_Name_Intent);
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(this);

        adapter = new Chat_Adapter(getActivity(), message);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // FETCH OLD MESSAGE FROM DATABASE
        chatDatabase();
        return v;
    }
    // FIREBASE REAL TIME DATABASE WHICH FETCH ALL MESSAGES (SYNC) FROM ONLINE DATABASE
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

    private synchronized void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        iterator = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            // GETTING DATA FROM FIREBASE DATABASE 

            Chat_Msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Chat_FROM = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Chat_FROM_ID = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Chat_TO = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Chat_TimeStamp = (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Chat_Type= (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Random_ID=(String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Chat_FCM_FROM= (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();
            Chat_FCM_TO= (String) ((DataSnapshot) iterator.next()).getValue();

            Log.d(TAG, "Chat Items " + Chat_Msg + " " + Random_ID);

            Chat_Database tempChatDatabase = new Chat_Database(getActivity());
            boolean hasValue = tempChatDatabase.CheckValueExist(Random_ID);
            Log.d(TAG,"DATABASE ALREADY HAS VALUE OF TIMESTAMP= "+hasValue);

            if (!hasValue) {
                Log.d(TAG,"DATABASE DON'T HAVE SAME ENTRY FOR TIME STAMP. ENTERED INTO HAS VALUE");
                Log.d(TAG,"Chat Message "+Chat_Msg);

           if (Chat_Type.equals("Typed_Message")) {
                Log.d(TAG, "VIEW TYPE IS Message " + Chat_Msg);
                long id = chat_database.Insert_Chat(Session.getUserID(),Room_Name_Intent, UserID_Intent, "Text", Chat_Msg, Chat_FROM, Chat_TO, Chat_TimeStamp, Chat_FCM_FROM, Chat_FCM_TO, Session.getPhoneNO(), UserPhone_Intent,Random_ID,UserImage_Intent,UserLastSeen_Intent,Chat_FROM_ID);

                //Adding Chat Data Into Database
                Log.d(TAG,"Database Entry ID "+id);

                if (id == 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Database Already Has Value Of This Random Id ");
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    continue;

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Database Don't Has Value Of This Random Id ");
                    Log.d(TAG,"Message Size "+message.size());
                    Chat_Wrapper chat_wrapper = new Chat_Wrapper(Chat_Msg, null, null, null, null, null, null, Chat_TimeStamp, UserPhone_Intent, UserImage_Intent, Chat_FROM, null,null,id);
                    message.add(chat_wrapper);
                    Log.d(TAG,"Message Size "+message.size());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Log.d(TAG,"Adapter Notified Data Set "+adapter.getItemCount());
                    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Moving to Bottom");
                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount());
                        }
                    });
                }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "MESSAGE ARRAY SIZE " + message.size());
        chat_database.isDatabaseClose();
}

    private void chatDatabase(){
        //Database Init and Filling Adapter
        Log.d(TAG,"Chat Database Function");
        chat_database=new Chat_Database(getActivity());
        chatCursor=chat_database.getUserChat(UserID_Intent);
        boolean checkDB_Exist=functions.DatabaseExist(getActivity(),"CHAT_DATABASE.DB");
        boolean chatItemsCounts=chatCursor.getCount()>0;
        chatCursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.d(TAG,"Value At Chat Database "+ checkDB_Exist+" "+chatItemsCounts);
        if (checkDB_Exist && chatCursor.getCount()>0 && chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_USER_ID")).equals(UserID_Intent)){

            Log.d(TAG,"Database Exist Chat Database");
            message.clear();
            chatCursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                database_rowID=chatCursor.getInt(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                database_userID=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("USER_ID"));
                database_RoomName =chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("ROOM_NAME"));
                database_ReceiverID=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_USER_ID"));
                database_MessageType=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("MESSAGE_TYPE"));
                database_Message=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("USER_MESSAGE"));
                database_MsgFrom=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("SENDER_NAME"));
                database_MsgTo=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_NAME"));
                database_TimeStamp=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("TIME_STAMP"));
                database_FCMfrom=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("SENDER_TOKEN"));
                database_FCMto=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_TOKEN"));
                database_LocalPath=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("DOWNLOADED_AT"));
                database_PhoneFrom=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("MY_PHONE"));
                database_PhoneTo=chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("OTHER_PHONE"));

                Log.d(TAG,"Value Of Database Message String = "+database_Message);
                Log.d(TAG,"Row ID of Database "+database_rowID);
                // Check Message Type


                    Log.d(TAG,"Message Type Is Text");
                    Chat_Wrapper text = new Chat_Wrapper(database_Message, null, null, null, null, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom,null,null,database_rowID);
                    message.add(text);



            }
            while(chatCursor.moveToNext());

            Room_Name_Intent = database_RoomName;
            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            chatCursor.close();
            boolean value = chat_database.isDatabaseClose();
            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Moving to Bottom");
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(message.size()-1);

                }
            });
            Log.d(TAG,"Value Of Database Close or Not "+value);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see your adapter implementation, but is it safe to assume that it is holding a reference to the message List and not copying the values into a new collection?

Comment: @eimmer see in `onCreateView` last line there is adapter implementation.

Comment: I see where it is initialized, not implemented. Is Chat_Adapter a class you define yourself, or supplied by Firebase?

Comment: @eimmer its custom adapter not firebase one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by digging bit into android lifecycle. As i mentioned above i am facing this issue only when i enter **ChatFragment** from notification. I was only activity state issue. Code was working. What i was doing i always recreate activity on notification tap ( In Firebase Code ).

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

After digging lots of code and changing multiple flags in `Intent`. Only `android:launchMode="singleTask"` solves my issue. Which only create activity if it's not exist. Now its not calling activity `onDestroy` method when tapping on notification. It's start activity from `onStart` which avoid activity to recreate.

I add this flag in **AndroidManifest's** NavigationDrawer activity tag.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Navigation_Drawer"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

These kind of issue is really headache for developers but i don't know that with this single line of code i can solve this issue. Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement the `LoaderCallbacks` here and to listen to the changes done in the database to update the `RecyclerView` accordingly. I have created a [repository in Github](https://github.com/masudias/SqliteDBReadWriteUpdate) here which shows the database read, write and update and making the changes in the database to have the proper effect in corresponding `RecyclerView` with registering a content observer to the database.

The whole idea is to have an observer attached to your database table which will notify you of any change in the table. When a change is detected the database read query will be generated automatically and on reloading the data again from your table will trigger the `RecyclerView` update inside `onLoadFinished` function.

I have a demo implementation in my Github project, which shows a list of users to be shown in a `RecyclerView` and updating the `RecyclerView` automatically without calling `notifyDataSetChanged`. Please check the adapter which controls the data to be shown in the `RecyclerView` again. This is the simplest implementation that you might have in your case avoiding any complexity.

Hope that helps.

**Update**

After going through the code, I have come up with some fixes that you should do. It is pretty difficult to understand why it is not working as you expected it to be because the code given is not very well formatted and complete. However, I can suggest you some key fixes here which might help.

In the `append_chat_conversation` function, you do not have to call `notifyDataSetChanged` each time you find a new chat message and add that to the `message`. I would like to suggest that, do not add the chat messages in your `message` list. You might get rid of the following `if-else` block. Just updating the chat database and inserting new chat messages into it is fine. So I would suggest you remove the following section.

```
if (id == 0) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Database Already Has Value Of This Random Id ");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    continue;

} else {
    Log.d(TAG,"Database Don't Has Value Of This Random Id ");
    Log.d(TAG,"Message Size "+message.size());
    Chat_Wrapper chat_wrapper = new Chat_Wrapper(Chat_Msg, null, null, null, null, null, null, Chat_TimeStamp, UserPhone_Intent, UserImage_Intent, Chat_FROM, null,null,id);
    message.add(chat_wrapper);
    Log.d(TAG,"Message Size "+message.size());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(TAG,"Adapter Notified Data Set "+adapter.getItemCount());
    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Moving to Bottom");
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount());
        }
    });
}
```

Call `chatDatabase` function before this line to load messages from the database.

```
// FETCH MESSAGE FROM DATABASE
chatDatabase();

Log.d(TAG, "MESSAGE ARRAY SIZE " + message.size());
chat_database.isDatabaseClose();
```

Now fix your `chatDatabase` function. You are creating a new `LinearLayoutManager` and assigning it to your `RecyclerView` each time you are calling the `chatDatabase` function. I would suggest removing it as well.

Modify your `chatDatabase` function like the following.

```
private void chatDatabase() {
    //Database Init and Filling Adapter
    Log.d(TAG, "Chat Database Function");
    chat_database = new Chat_Database(getActivity());
    chatCursor = chat_database.getUserChat(UserID_Intent);
    boolean checkDB_Exist = functions.DatabaseExist(getActivity(), "CHAT_DATABASE.DB");
    boolean chatItemsCounts = chatCursor.getCount() > 0;
    chatCursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.d(TAG, "Value At Chat Database " + checkDB_Exist + " " + chatItemsCounts);
    if (checkDB_Exist && chatCursor.getCount() > 0 && chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_USER_ID")).equals(UserID_Intent)) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Database Exist Chat Database");
        message.clear();
        chatCursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            database_rowID = chatCursor.getInt(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
            database_userID = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("USER_ID"));
            database_RoomName = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("ROOM_NAME"));
            database_ReceiverID = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_USER_ID"));
            database_MessageType = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("MESSAGE_TYPE"));
            database_Message = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("USER_MESSAGE"));
            database_MsgFrom = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("SENDER_NAME"));
            database_MsgTo = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_NAME"));
            database_TimeStamp = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("TIME_STAMP"));
            database_FCMfrom = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("SENDER_TOKEN"));
            database_FCMto = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_TOKEN"));
            database_LocalPath = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("DOWNLOADED_AT"));
            database_PhoneFrom = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("MY_PHONE"));
            database_PhoneTo = chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("OTHER_PHONE"));

            Log.d(TAG, "Value Of Database Message String = " + database_Message);
            Log.d(TAG, "Row ID of Database " + database_rowID);
            // Check Message Type


            Log.d(TAG, "Message Type Is Text");
            Chat_Wrapper text = new Chat_Wrapper(database_Message, null, null, null, null, null, null, database_TimeStamp, database_PhoneTo, UserImage_Intent, database_MsgFrom, null, null, database_rowID);
            message.add(text);

        } while (chatCursor.moveToNext());

        Room_Name_Intent = database_RoomName;

        adapter.setChatMessages(message); // Add a public function in your adapter to set the chat messages 
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        chatCursor.close();
        boolean value = chat_database.isDatabaseClose();
        recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Moving to Bottom");
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(message.size() - 1);

            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "Value Of Database Close or Not " + value);
    }
}
```

The `setChatMessages` function in your adapter will look something like this.

```
public void setChatMessages(ArrayList<Message> messageList) {
    this.message = messageList;
}
```

Comment: Can you please guide, Because it only happen when we come to app from notification otherwise its working fine. I mentioned above cases when it works fine. Can you tweak our code bit to make it work ?

Comment: I am checking it. Getting back with result. if not working i will try to provide you complete code with well formatted way so you can get it easily.

Comment: I have few doubts. Is it good to fetch complete message list whenever new message received. calling database regularly is it good as performance for device. I am working on your code i will update you asap. Great thanks for your help.

Comment: Getting continue crash with `Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2 at line `   `if (checkDB_Exist && chatCursor.getCount() > 0 && chatCursor.getString(chatCursor.getColumnIndex("RECEIVER_USER_ID")).equals(UserID_Intent)) {`
Double check cursor is move to first but still getting this issue. If you say i will provide you complete code so you can get issue easily. Thanks & Regards.

Comment: I think this error is solely refers to the problem with the data saved in SQLite. You can share the code in Github if you think this has no privacy problem. However, a SO question should be clear and brief enough to describe the problem clearly.

Comment: i will tell my team share code on github and soon update you

Comment: Please check complete fragment code. https://gist.github.com/varun7952/b7bcec6c806dfa941416f5a9c2e1c5c0

Comment: Adapter for chat Fragment - https://gist.github.com/varun7952/94642830fce5b06d5cfb4a70486eee35