# Launch Fragment on notification click without losing state

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, push-notification

I have chat app where is also launched directly by notification click. Chat fragment also launches manually by click inside the app.

I want if user tap home button while on chat fragment and then click on the notification, it should launch in the last state and don't call activity's `onDestroy` then `onCreate`.

Launch `Fragment` by notification in `Activity` like this.

```
((AppCompatActivity)context).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.Navigation_Main_Layout, screenFragment,"Chat").commit();
```

I am handling the notification from `FirebaseMessagingService`

```
public class FireBase_Messaging_Service extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static final String TAG="###FireBase MSG###";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION=5;
    String UserName;
    String ID;
    String Msg;

    Map<String,String> data;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d(TAG,"From "+remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
            data = remoteMessage.getData();
            Log.d(TAG,"Message Data "+remoteMessage.getData());
            data = remoteMessage.getData();

            UserName = data.get("name");
            ID = data.get("ID");
            Msg = data.get("Message");

            showNotification(Msg,ID,UserName);
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Message Notification Body "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
           // Toast.makeText(this, "Notification "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private void showNotification(String Message,String ID,String UserName) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Show Notification "+Message+" "+ID);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, Navigation_Drawer.class);
        intent.putExtra("Type","Text");
        //intent.putExtra("Type",MsgType);
        intent.putExtra("ID",ID);
        intent.putExtra("uname",UserName);
        intent.putExtra("Message",Msg);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,NOTIFICATION,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.black);
        String ChannelID = "Message";
        notificationChannel(ChannelID,"Chat");
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(),ChannelID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.default_x)
                .setColor(color)
                .setContentTitle(UserName)
                .setContentText(Message)
                .setChannelId(ChannelID)
                .setTicker("My App")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS)
                .setLights(0xff00ff00, 1000, 500) // To change Light Colors
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(Message))//For Expandable View
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION,builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
    }

    private void notificationChannel (String ChannelID, String channelName) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel  channel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelID,channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

In above code, I tried `Intent` with different flags, such as `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,Intent`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` etc. However, it always calls activity's (Navigation Drawer) `onDestroy` first and then `onCreate`. Then it launches fragment from start.

How can I avoid app to recreate `Activity` and `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was loading activity and fragment at first launch without any flags. When i receive notification i was adding a flag which make activity to call `onDestroy` first then `onCreate`.

I add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in Manifest file under activity tag whenever activity first create. It helps me to avoid recreate Fragment in Activity.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Navigation_Drawer"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

As per my knowledge, the desired behaviour from Android activity conflicts with the Android lifecycle of the activity and fragment. When the user presses the back or home button, the activity or fragment will go through the `onPause` and `onDestroy` following the life cycle of that activity or fragment instance. There is no way you can avoid it unless you are calling a `finish` in your activity which avoids the `onDestroy` function call in an activity. However, you do not want to finish the activity, you want to use the same activity and want that activity not to be recreated.

So I was thinking of a different way of solving your problem. Mostly the problem with recreating an activity or fragment directly indicates to the resources to be fetched and for heavy resources to be fetched while initializing an activity or fragment is an overhead. So we might avoid fetching the resources to be used in an activity or fragment when the resources are already available in the saved instance state.

For example, when you are fetching some data saved in a SQLite database in the `onCreate` function of your activity, you might do not want to fetch it again on orientation changes of your activity, which forcefully recreates the activity. In that case, you might need to choose a loader (I am talking about `CursorLoader` with the implementation of `LoaderCallbacks`) which survives the Activity recreation. The implementation with the loader will not fetch the data again from SQLite database if fetched already and will serve the data on recreating an activity.

Another beautiful thing that I want to recommend is to use `ViewModel`. You may find the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) explaining the implementation. `ViewModel` survives the Activity recreation you can save the instance state using a `ViewModel` which will reduce the load time.

The whole point is, you might not be able to trick the lifecycle functions, but you might choose using data models which will survive the recreation of your activities and fragments.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement it. I want to tell you that onDestroy is calling after i tap on notification then oncreate.

Comment: I think this is for the intent flags those you are trying to set. Some intent flags will recreate the activity destroying any previous instance of the activity.

Comment: I think you might consider having a look [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack).

Comment: actually our main issue is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50842745/recyclerview-adapters-notifydatasetchanged-not-updating-recyclerview.   And i think losing state is causing the issue

Comment: My pleasure. I am looking into that issue as well.

Comment: Thanks that would be really great help for me and my team. If you spare sometime to resolve our issue.

Comment: Please check the answer of the question that you have provided here.

Comment: I leave comment there please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173243/discussion-between-ritu-and-reaz-murshed).